# Error: Multiple analyses requested in LTSpice

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, ltspice, current-mirror

I am running the following simulation in LT spice but I am getting the following error:

```
Multiple analyses requested
.trans 0 100m 90m 1m
.op
```

Here is my circuit.[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: While I posted an answer, I wonder what you were trying to achieve - do you want to see a plot of Vout vs time?

Answer (score 2):

It's because you spelled it `.trans` instead of `.tran`.  Make that small change and it will work, but see the other answers/comments on why the `.op` will be ignored when `.tran` is present.

Comment: Nice catch! I didn't see it, I'm getting old :-( The funny part is that if you comment out `.op` the "edit simulation cmd" popup appears, expecting you to choose a simulation type. This might be a bug in the parser.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen LTspice's UI seems to be very strict in the simulation command naming in order to make sure the user doesn't go completely off the rails.  Also interesting is if you run a raw `.net`, it doesn't care if you use `.trans`...but then it also doesn't do the auto-ignore anymore if you throw an `.op` in there.  Meh, whatever, it's impossible to handle all corner cases.

Comment: Well, truth be told, the mistake here is the syntax, but the way LTspice reacts is misleading: if there are more than one simulation command, `.tran` and `.ac`, for example, but even duplicates, when clicking "run" there is a window forcing you to select one of those commands, after which it works. But here... Oh well, it's minor.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do an operation point analysis with `.op` or a transient analysis with `.tran` but not both at the same time.

So you need to remove one of the directives or mark one as comment (via right click).

There is also an option for the transient simulation to skip the operation point analysis but that has to appear in the `.tran` line and is named `uic` and not `op`.

If you need both results, you have to run them sequentially selecting only one at a time - or there might be a possibility to extract the operation point analysis from the transient analysis, but I'm not sure and have to look that up.

Comment: It's true that only one analysis is possible at a time, but `.op`, in this case, is discarded in favour of `.tran`. At least, it does so with a Windows version. The error log shows this line: `*op`, so it's commented out. Maybe the Mac version thinks different (judging by OP's picture)? It wouldn't be the first time.